# why I have to disable javascript in my page to see my mailchimp form works?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, mailchimp

I'm trying to add a mailchimp form hosted in another domaine to my new page and i can submit my subscription only if I turn off javascript ?

i don't know why and in which situation this problem happen ?
Because my form works perfectly here.

**The code**

```js
(function($) {window.fnames = new Array(); window.ftypes = new Array();fnames[0]='EMAIL';ftypes[0]='email';fnames[8]='MMERGE8';ftypes[8]='text';fnames[3]='MMERGE3';ftypes[3]='text';fnames[4]='MMERGE4';ftypes[4]='text';fnames[5]='MMERGE5';ftypes[5]='text';fnames[6]='MMERGE6';ftypes[6]='text';fnames[7]='MMERGE7';ftypes[7]='text';}(jQuery));var $mcj = jQuery.noConflict(true);
```

```html
<link href="http://cdn-images.mailchimp.com/embedcode/classic-10_7.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<style type="text/css">
#mc_embed_signup { background:#fff;  clear:left; }
    
#mc_embed_signup form  { padding: 20px 0px 0px 0px }
#mc_embed_signup .button { 
border-radius:0px!important; 
background:#fff; 
color:#282828; 
padding: 15px 0px 0px 0px; 
height: 50px; 
font-size: 11px; 
}
    
    
#mc_embed_signup .button:hover { background:#fff; color:#d2c6af; } 
    
#mc_embed_signup .mc-field-group input { 
border-radius:0px!important;
border-top:0px!important;
border-left:0px!important;
border-right:0!important;
border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
max-width:250px!important; 
}
    
#mc_embed_signup .mc-field-group input:focus { 
border-bottom: 1px solid #282828;
}
        
    
#mc_embed_signup #mc-embedded-subscribe-form div.mce_inline_error { 
font-size: 11px; margin: 0px 0 0em 0;padding: 5px 0px;
}
   
</style>
    
<div id="mc_embed_signup">

<form action="http://www.domaine.us2.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=67c8e1302463c1a5125704ad4&amp;id=0e0ead4532" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>
    
<div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll">
<div class="indicates-required"></div>
    
<div class="mc-field-group">
    
<input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="required email" id="mce-EMAIL" placeholder="Email*">
</div>
    
    
    
<div class="mc-field-group">
<input type="text" value="" name="MMERGE8" class="" id="mce-MMERGE8" placeholder="Last Name">
</div>
    
    
    
<div class="mc-field-group">
<input type="text" value="" name="MMERGE3" class="" id="mce-MMERGE3" placeholder="Country">
</div>
    
    
    
<div id="mce-responses" class="clear">
<div class="response" id="mce-error-response" style="display:none"></div>
<div class="response" id="mce-success-response" style="display:none"></div>
</div>    
    
    
    
<div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;" aria-hidden="true">
<input type="text" name="b_67c8e1302463c1a5773704ad4_0e0eaf4632" tabindex="-1" value="">
</div>
    
    
    
<div class="clear">
<input type="submit" value="Subscribe&nbsp;&nbsp;→" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button">
</div>
</div>
</form>
</div>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://s3.amazonaws.com/downloads.mailchimp.com/js/mc-validate.js'></script>
```

Comment: Probably because that Tool doesn't know about your jQuery dependency

Comment: so where can I test my file to see if all it's ok ? because I don't know if there are errors or no, i red it a lot !!

Comment: Try jsFiddle with your html.

Comment: Don't forget to select jQuery Framework and extension.

Comment: how can  I se errors in jsfiddle ?

Comment: add jquery framework

Comment: Is any error present in your page?

Comment: no there is any error, that's why I want to test my file because there is nothing in my consol ?

Comment: I have add this idea because I have some problems to add a mailchimp form and this function $('#myid').html($('#myid').html());

Comment: I think all these problems can come from my js file

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Simulator try to run it in your browser(especially google chrome) and go 
 **right click->inspect element->console tab** 
here you can see the errors and its line number

Comment: but if we have any error so that's ok ? because I have trouble with mailchimp form ?

Comment: I dont get it what you are try to say?

Comment: when I want to click on subscribe nothing change ad I don't know where is my mistakes, when I read documentation i see that the problem can come from the js part of if you ever use a form in the page, and that's not in my situation

Comment: i got this error when i click subscribe



http://www.mydomaine.us2.list-manage.com/subscribe/post-json?u=67c8e1302463…04ad4_0e0eaf4632=&subscribe=Subscribe%C2%A0%C2%A0%E2%86%92&_=1477049025187
 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)